# Orthogonality constraints when formulating SVD as optimization problem

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, orthogonality, svd

I am working on a project that requires me to formulate the singular value decomposition (SVD) as an optimization problem. In order to do this I need to require that $U$ and $V$ in $A =USV^T$ are orthogonal. Thus my problem looks something like this:

$$\arg\min_{U,\Sigma,V}\left\Vert A-U\Sigma V^{T}\right\Vert _{F}^{2}$$

subject to

$$ U^{T} U = I,\quad V^{T} V = I,\quad \mbox{diag}(\Sigma) \geq 0, \quad \mbox{rank}(U) = \mbox{rank}(V)=n $$

(As a side note I am not too worried about enforcing the size and rank of U and V, nor the sign of the singular values.)

I have no idea how to handle the orthogonality constraints. I am new to optimization. I have seen the paper [A feasible method for optimization with orthogonality constraints](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/A-feasible-method-for-optimization-with-Wen-Yin/5d76202ebe37936b4c3796d9cbbe7be5b60f93d0). It says that orthogonality constraints are not convex, however someone I am working with assures me that the above problem is nonlinear convex.
I could attempt to use the transformation mentioned in the paper, but I have seen similar problems with orthogonality constraints that don't mention a Cayley transform, which makes me wonder if there are other methods.

Here is what I would like to figure out:

- Is there a general way to handle the constraints $U^TU = I$ or even $\|u_i\| = 1$?
- Can I formulate the orthogonality constraints as bilinear constraints?
- Is there a known formulation of the SVD as an optimization problem? (along with solution algorithm ideally)

As of now I may try to solve for PCA as an optimization problem and use that to find the SVD of my centered dataset. I would prefer however to be able to find the SVD of the original dataset.

Comment: As expressed, it is certainly not a convex problem. If $U,V$ satisfy the constraint then so does $-U,-V$ but clearly their average does not.

Comment: Uwe Helmke, John B. Moore, [Optimization and Dynamical Systems](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~john/papers/BOOK/B04.PDF), 2nd edition, March 1996.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that you can approach this problem using **optimization over manifolds**.

The easiest example to consider is solving the following eigenvalue problem using the Rayleigh quotient (only numerator is important):
$$\max_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n} x^TAx$$
subject to: 
$$||x||=1$$
The maximum is the largest eigenvalue of A (it must be diagonalizable of course), and the value of $x$ that gives the maximum is the associated eigenvector.
You can think of the unit length constraint on the vector $x$ as forcing it to lie on the surface of an (n-1)-sphere. This is easy to picture mentally if n=2 or 3.

In my question above the constraint $U^TU=I$ is equivalent to solving along a Grassmann manifold (or Stiefel manifold I believe) for the variable $U$. The same goes for $V$.

I found the following MATLAB package to perform such optimizations:
https://manopt.org/index.html

See this blog post for an intro:
https://afonsobandeira.wordpress.com/2015/03/16/optimizing-in-smooth-waters-optimization-on-manifolds/

Comment: Optimization on a Stiefel manifold is the appropriate way to frame this problem is one must pose it as a constrained optimization problem